# Add a custom resharper rule to inspect property presence

Tags: c#, resharper, rider

I want to add inspection with ReSharper/Rider to highlight such cases:

I have some abstract `GenericBase` class. It have some `DoStuff` abstract method. As a result, all inherited classes should implement this method. But if class have not any stuff to place it to the this method, it should override property `DontWantToDoAnyStuff` to make it result `true` for performance reasons.

So, I want to add inspection to find all classes with empty `DoStuff` method and without `DontWantToDoAnyStuff` property. Am I able to do this with resharper?

BTW, I'm not able to globally refactore the system to avoid such situations at all. =)

Comment: Resharper suggests code style improvements and helps you detect potentials problems with the compiler. I think the problem you have is on an architectural level and should not be solved with resharper.

Comment: So...  Presumably there is a line of code in the base class which says something like `if (!DontWantToDoAnyStuff) { DoStuff();}` ?  pretty sure the compiler would recognise this as a no-op if the `DoStuff()` method was empty and just optimise it out.  Have you actually measured a performance problem?  If you could provide numbers then you could make the case (to management? clients?) for spending time to refactor this into something that could be (at least) adequately covered by unit tests.

Comment: As far as I know, we need to run `DoStuff` in separate thread, so we should spend some time to create thread, etc... Anyway, let's just assume that architecture is immutable.